# what is a variable/object/thing starting with a # in ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am new to Ruby, so go easy :).

Anyway, I am trying to work out some stuff in the chef-provisioning-aws gem. One thing in particular is that there is an object called:

```
new_resource.driver.ec2_client
```

When I do an inspect on that object it returns exactly this:

```
#<Aws::EC2::Client>
```

So, my question is: what is this? What sort of "thing" in Ruby starts with a pound sign (hash) and has <...> in it?

Much appreciated.

Comment: it is default string representation of a complex ruby object, which doesn't have friendlier string representation. In this case, `Aws::EC2::Client` object.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html) would help. I say "perhaps" because I know nothing of *chef* or the *Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud*, but I do know how to Google. I don't know about the leading pound sign, but that often indicates a class instance.

Comment: Rather than "something like", please show precisely what is returned.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is actually what it returned:  #<Aws::EC2::Client>

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good call. I have done that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The output of Ruby's inspect method is roughly like this unless you override it:

```
"#<#{self.class}:0x#{self.object_id.to_s(16)}"
```

So in other words: `"#<ClassName:0xobject_id in hex>"`.

```
 class Foo ; end
 Foo.new.inspect
 #=> "#<Foo:0x007ffe0eeea520>"
```

It seems that for `Aws::EC2::Client` it was overriden and does not include the object id.

Comment: The `object_id` has to be shifted 1 bit to the left and the output is padded with zeros, i.e. it's more like `sprintf('#<%s:%#016x>', self.class, self.object_id << 1)`

Comment: @Stefan Hence the "roughly".

Answer (score 2):

It's the default implementation of the [inspect method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) (although then the object ID should be included). It may be useful in some situations to implement your own method, so you can get an instant overview of what you want to know about this object. The `#` is just a random character and has no further meaning here.